# How do I create a 3D matrix from multiple imread variables?

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

I'm trying to write a program that takes a matrix composed of multiple png files which are saved as sub-matrices within the matrix. I have 10 png files of identical size saved as image_1, image_2 etc., and I want to be able to go through each image individually in a loop later on. Is creating a 3D matrix the best way to do this, and if so, how will I use it for the above purpose later on?

Comment: I'm sure you'll figure from the tag I meant to say that this is in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to create a 3D matrix from your images, you can do something along the following lines:

```
>> image_1 = rand(5);
>> image_2 = rand(5);
>> [m, n] = size(image_1);
>> images = zeros(m, n, 2);
>> 
for ii=1:2
    eval(sprintf('images(:,:,%d) = image_%d;', ii, ii));
end
>>
```

The result would be something like:

```
>> images

images(:,:,1) =

    0.9037    0.0305    0.6099    0.1829    0.1679
    0.8909    0.7441    0.6177    0.2399    0.9787
    0.3342    0.5000    0.8594    0.8865    0.7127
    0.6987    0.4799    0.8055    0.0287    0.5005
    0.1978    0.9047    0.5767    0.4899    0.4711


images(:,:,2) =

    0.0596    0.0967    0.6596    0.4538    0.1734
    0.6820    0.8181    0.5186    0.4324    0.3909
    0.0424    0.8175    0.9730    0.8253    0.8314
    0.0714    0.7224    0.6490    0.0835    0.8034
    0.5216    0.1499    0.8003    0.1332    0.0605

>>
```

If you feel that the individual `image_ii` variables are unnecessary afterwards, you can simply clear them as follows:

```
>> 
for ii=1:2
    eval(sprintf('clear image_%d;', ii));
end
>>
```

The new 3D matrix may be used later as `images(:,:,1)`, `images(4,3,2)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the filename format of the images, this is fairly simple; for example:

```
directory = pwd; % select working directory (but could be anything)
Nimages = 5;

% Use a cell array to initially store results, 
% as we don't know how big the images are yet
myImages = cell(Nimages, 1); 

for iImg = 1:Nimages
    % Build file name
    imgFilename = sprintf('Image_%i', iImg);
    % Make it fully qualified using directory
    imgFilename = fullfile(directory, imgFilename);
    % Load the image
    myImages{iImg} = imread(imgFilename);
end

% This will convert from cell to 3D matrix:
myImages = cat(3, myImages{:})
```

You can later access these images using

```
myImages(:, :, n)
```

where `n` is the image number.